# Insert/Update Issue (Same record repeated, no more can be entered)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a bit baffled here, and my code is a bit too lengthy to post it all, but I'll provide a logical list of the operations in hand and can provide the code where needed if it helps, but the problem is weird and I don't think it's to do with the code. It's a standard upload form for an article website.

1. On first load, assign random `article_ID`
2. Check if `article_ID` already exists. If it does, repeat step 1
3. On save (submit), insert `article_ID` (the only required value [for testing purposes], the rest can be `NULL`)
4. Any of other fields entered are checked for content, and if there is some entered update where `article_ID = $article_ID`.

It's quite a simple system, make a template of an article with an `article_ID` where all the other fields can be `NULL`. The user adds the content piece by piece saving along the way until all the fields are entered so the article can be published.

However, the first time I got it working, an `article_ID` was assigned and the template inserted. Now I can't insert any other records, and more oddly still if I delete that record and then create a new form instance with a new `article_ID` and INSERT, it just keeps adding the same record with the old `article_ID`, even though the form has no session variables with that old `article_ID` still stored.

Has anyone had something similar?

Database Structure

```
  `article_ID`            int(10)      NOT NULL,
  `author_ID`             int(5)       NOT NULL,
  `article_title`         varchar(50)  NOT NULL,
  `article_subtitleshort` varchar(120) default NULL,
  `article_subtitlelong`  varchar(180) default NULL,
  `article_category`      varchar(20)  NOT NULL,
  `article_featureimage`  varchar(15)  default NULL,
  `article_icon`          varchar(15)  default NULL,
  `article_publishdate`   varchar(12)  default NULL,
  `article_lastsavedate`  varchar(12)  NOT NULL,
  `article_status`        varchar(11)  NOT NULL default 'unpublished',
  `article_firstimage`    varchar(15)  default NULL,
  `article_intro`         varchar(600) default NULL,
  `article_firsttext`     blob,
  `article_secondimage`   varchar(15)  default NULL,
  `article_secondtext`    blob,
  `article_thirdimage`    varchar(15)  default NULL,
  `article_youtube`       varchar(50)  default NULL,
  `article_gallery`       varchar(10)  default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`article_ID`)
```

**Relevant Code** http://snippi.com/s/57j8i7e

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: Relevant code: http://snippi.com/s/57j8i7e

Comment: because there is a file system that uses the ID and if auto increment were to be used then if there were 47 records, the 47th was deleted and then another one was made, it'd be assigned 47 but that would make it point to the old article's files.

Comment: With the creation of the article template (the first INSERT), how can I then retrieve the auto-incremented ID before updating that record with content from other fields?

Comment: I've found the issue. The DB only accepts article_ID's that are less than the existing ones. Why might this be?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the `INSERT` is failing because you are inserting a `INTs` as `VARCHARs`. Change it as follow - Remove the single quotes passing it through as `VARCHAR` incorrectly.

Also verify that your SELECT statement will return record as you are using the same logic when you pass the `$article_ID` i.e. remove the single quotes. Also not necessary to check for the random value.

Please make use of `AUTO_INCREMENT` for article_ID instead of randomly generating the value.

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO articles (author_ID) VALUES ($author_ID)");
```

`article_ID` will be populated with a unique value

Comment: And else try this query: mysql_query("INSERT INTO articles (article_ID, author_ID) VALUES (".$article_ID.",".$author_ID.")");

Comment: Okay, that has allowed me to add 1 extra record, but then the same problem arises. The initial ID is entered for the second record and then no more after that.

Comment: @Marijke - what will this do?

Comment: Wait, I tested your code and I think I fixed it by unsetting the variables after the INSERT.

Comment: Which variables? $article_ID needs to be kept as it is used for the UPDATE statements later when adding content to other fields.

Comment: OKay the DB structure limited the inserting of any number higher than the recurring article_ID, which is why I thought it was updating the same record. The Int value wasn't allowing any number higher than 2147483647, which is the highest value and 32 bit Int can hold!

Comment: There use `AUTO_INCREMENT`